# Can't set value for div button created in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to dynamically add a button to a div in JS. I can do this where no button value is set (i.e blank button) but as soon as I try to add a value for the button the div disappears. Any idea why this is not working?

```js
var btn = document.createElement("button");
btn.id = "myBtn";
document.getElementById("myBtn").value = "test"; // This is causing the problem
div.appendChild(btn);
```

Comment: `btn.innerText = "test";` Also the button is not part of the DOM until after you append it so don't use document.getElementById until after that

Answer (score 1):

You have mixed up 2 lines. Switch the last 2 lines to:

```
document.getElementById("myBtn").value = "test"; // This is causing the problem
div.appendChild(btn);
```

document.getElementById only looks for elements that are added to the DOM already. So if you add it to the DOM and then get it by id, you won't have any problem. You actually don't even need to use document.getElementById at all in the example you've shown. You already have a reference to the HTMLButtonElement.

All you need is:

```
var btn = document.createElement("button");
btn.id = "myBtn";
btn.value = "test"; // This is causing the problem
div.appendChild(btn);
```

By the way, are you intending to have 'test' be the button text? Then you should use:

```
btn.innerHTML = "test"
```

instead of:

```
btn.value = "test".
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I used the btn.innerHTML after the DIV and this works.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to get the button by id, you already have it as the variable btn, and not in the document.
Try instead:

`btn.value = "test";`